# printf format string warnings for a long unsigned integer

Tags: c, linux

I have problem with my c code, g++ compiler gives an error about long unsigned int when I try to printf same values. Here is my code and the errors that I get:

```
as3.c: warning: format %s expects type char *, but argument 2 has type onion
as3.c: warning: format %d expects type int, but argument 3 has type long unsigned int
as3.c: warning: format %d expects type int, but argument 3 has type long unsigned int
as3.c: warning: format %d expects type int, but argument 5 has type long unsigned int
as3.c: warning: format %d expects type int, but argument 2 has type long unsigned int
```

```
#define NUM1 5.557111111111111
#define NUM2 1937006915
#define NUM3 1668248096
#define NUM4 8555

#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
char  * a;
double num;
int * i;
}onion;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
onion myoni;
char array[] = "TESTING";
int array2[] = { NUM2, NUM1, NUM3 };
myoni.a = array; 
printf("char: %s, %d\n",myoni,sizeof(myoni.a));
myoni.num = NUM1; 
printf("double: %10.15f, %d\n", myoni.num, sizeof(myoni.num));
myoni.i = array2;
printf("int: %d %d %d, %d\n", myoni.i[0], myoni.i[1],myoni.i[2], sizeof(myoni.i));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
printf("char: %s, %d\n",myoni,sizeof(myoni.a));
```

use:

```
printf("char: %s, %zu\n",myoni.a,sizeof(myoni.a));
```

That is, pass a `char *` for `s` conversion specifier and use the `%zu` conversion specification for the result of the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Cast the value from `sizeof` to `unsigned long` (the type is `size_t` and, in C99, you can use `"%zu"` to print values of type `size_t`) and use `"%lu"` in the `printf` specifier

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof something);
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof (sometype));
/* C99 below */
printf("%zu\n", sizeof something);
printf("%zu\n", sizeof (sometype));
```

The type `onion` has a member of type `char*`. I suspect that's what you wanted to print

```
printf("%s\n", myoni.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first warning, don't use `onion` use `onion.a` like so:

```
    #define NUM1 5.557111111111111
    #define NUM2 1937006915
    #define NUM3 1668248096
    #define NUM4 8555

    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef union
    {
      char * a;
      double num;
      int * i;
    } onion;

    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
      onion myoni;
      char array[] = "TESTING";
      int array2[] =
      { NUM2, NUM1, NUM3 };
      myoni.a = array;
      printf("char: %s, %d\n", myoni.a, sizeof(myoni.a));
      myoni.num = NUM1;
      printf("double: %10.15f, %d\n", myoni.num, sizeof(myoni.num));
      myoni.i = array2;
      printf("int: %d %d %d, %d\n", myoni.i[0], myoni.i[1], myoni.i[2],
          sizeof(myoni.i));

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: i think its %lu but anyway thank you. Still couldnt fix first error

Comment: where am I going to use "onion" instead of onion

Comment: For the first, use `myoni.a`. The `sizeof` there will only give you the size of a `char*` though. Same for `sizeof(myoni.i)`, will return the size of an int pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The first warning is due to this line:

```
printf("char: %s, %d\n",myoni,sizeof(myoni.a));
```

`%s` expects type `char *`, but you have passed a variable of type `onion`.  You need to explicitly use the `a` member of `myoni`, which has type `char *` as required:

```
printf("char: %s, %d\n",myoni.a,sizeof(myoni.a));
```

The second warning is due to the use of the `sizeof` macro, which returns a `long unsigned int`, as stated in the warning message.  The format specifier for `long unsigned int` is `%lu` (Long Unsigned), not `%d`.  i.e:

```
printf("char: %s, %lu\n",myoni.a,sizeof(myoni.a));
```

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a macro; it returns a value of type `size_t` (which may, or may not, correspond to `long unsigned int` on different implementations).